В чем проблема с импортами?
Имеется такая структура проекта Python:

Вот код main.py:
from os import getenv
from dotenv import load_dotenv

from src.api_clients.yandex_api_clients import StaticAPIClient

def main():
    load_dotenv()

    sac = StaticAPIClient(getenv('STATIC_API_KEY'))

    print(sac.base_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Вот код yandex_api_clients.py:
from requests import Session

from api_client_interfaces import IAPIClient
from .. geoposition.coordinate import Coordinate

class StaticAPIClient(IAPIClient): pass

class HTTPGeocoderClient(IAPIClient): pass

При запуске интерпретатора через консоль непосредственно в папке map-peeker через python main.py выдает:
from api_client_interfaces import IAPIClient
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api_client_interfaces'

Как решить? Я не понимаю, как работают импорты в CPython.

Попробуйте варианты from ./api_client_interfaces и from src.api_clients.api_client_interfaces

Спасибо! Я просто добавил точку перед api_client_interface

А, точно, без дроби нужно. Я сам в этих импортах путаюсь.
